# Django 1.7 database error

Tags: python, django, database

i had some trouble with this error..
I tried a manage.py flush but when i syncdb to get a fresh superadmin account it just say this error
I have tried alot but nothing works :( help me!

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: debug_toolbar
  Apply all migrations: admin, home, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying home.0008_auto_20141204_1209...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 107, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field_by_name(self.name)[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 185, in remove_field
    self._remake_table(model, delete_fields=[field])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 135, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 99, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

this is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from urlparse import urlparse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import migrations
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime




class Topic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    postit = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    createdat = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    '''createdat = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedat = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def created(self):
        return self.createdat

    ''' 

    def updated(self):
        return self.updatedat  

    def timer(self):
        return self.createdat


    def who(self):
        return self.user

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.postit


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    Topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name


# Create your models here.

class texting(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField() 

class Chatting(models.Model):

    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    '''
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)




    self hyper link?
    @property
    def domain(self):
        return urlparse(self.url).netloc

'''
```

Comment: appears to be a syntax error in your migration file `home.0008_auto_20141204_1209...`

Comment: Why are you using `syncdb` with django 1.7?

Comment: I really don't understand the new migration thing. and i'm new to django. Just want to learn & experiment

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Hye,

try the following steps-:

1)Delete all the previous migration files.

2)then run this------------------------>python manage.py migrations

3)then run --------------------------->python manage.py migrate.

Hope this will be helpfull.If any other issues please comment

thanks

Comment: Will try, but i have no clue how to delete migration files

Comment: Ok i deleted all files, seems to work again ! thanks.

Comment: Pleasure-Always happy to help:-)

Comment: I would generally avoid deleting all previous migration files .... that can really mess up your migration history, particularly if you're on a project with other developers

Comment: Deleting migrations is a terrible solution! You've not identified the root cause of the problem

Answer (score 3):

There's a [bug in the sqlite schema editor](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24424).

Comment: [This pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/4325/files) from that ticket fixed it for me.